# Hi I am trying to export this data to a csv file but cant figure it out does anyone know? help is greatly apprciated

Tags: powershell, csv

```
$infile = "C:\Temp\check.txt"  
$users = Get-Content $infile  
foreach ($user in $users){ Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $user -or samaccountname -like $user} | Select Name, SamAccountName,Enabled } | export-csv "C:\temp\Git.csv"
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for your response. The code should export a list of users who are disabled or enabled within active directory. Esentially the code does work but unfortunatley I cannot get all the data to export to an excel file from the txt file. When i Run this without trying to export it works fine and I can see the data clearly. I just want it to also export to .csv sorry if I'm not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a flow control statement (like a `foreach(...){...}` loop) as a command element in a **pipeline expression**.

The idiomatic workaround is to use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```
$infile = "C:\Temp\check.txt"  
$users = Get-Content $infile  
$users |ForEach-Object { 
    $user = $_
    Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $user -or samaccountname -like $user} | Select Name, SamAccountName,Enabled 
} | Export-csv "C:\temp\Git.csv"
```

Alternatively, you can wrap the whole statement in a scriptblock and then use that as the first command in your pipeline:

```
$infile = "C:\Temp\check.txt"  
$users = Get-Content $infile
& {
    foreach($user in $users) { 
        Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $user -or samaccountname -like $user} | Select Name, SamAccountName,Enabled 
    } 
} | Export-csv "C:\temp\Git.csv"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for yo0ur help that worked perfectly